# jUDDI configurations and usage for eclipse and tomcat

Tags: registry, uddi, juddi

Hello everyone,
              I am new to web services and i want to create my own registry using JUDDI and Apache tomcat server and Eclipse. can any one give me the process and working steps for creating private registry in jUDDI. i am java developer.

Answer (score 0):

jUDDI PMC here. You'll probably want to start with the website: http://juddi.apach.org and download the latest distribution (3.2 as of Nov 2014). Within the distribution is a readme file to help you get the server up and running. It's pretty much an unzip, then start tomcat job. It's all preconfigured.

To get started using it, you'll want to follow the guides, located at http://juddi.apache.org/docs.html. Specifically the "Apache jUDDI Client and GUI Guide" (Client Dev & GUI User Guide).

Next, you'll want to check out the "juddi-examples" projects, which is in the client distribution as well as javadocs. The source for everything is available via git.

Finally, as an additional resource, there's the juddi user mailing list. Traffic is low, but we answer questions pretty quickly.

Side Note: 3.2.1 will be released shortly